# How to set defined image weight in Drupal

Tags: media

I just now noticed this:

My uploaded image for article has more weight in kb as my uploaded original image;

I have set my GD toolkit image quality to 100% because I am compressing images myself as I wish (in IrfanView) ...

So, my original image is of dimensions: 549 X 803 **58.1 kb**

In webpage I see image of dimensions: 328 X 480 and **113.73 kb !!!**

- I expect the image to be of my defined weight ; or even smaller , if the size is smaller; but not larger....

Answer (score 0):

If you've set the quality to 100% it's likely that that is why it's resulting in a larger file size. You may be setting it to a higher quality compression than the original photo had. You should try to find a balance between compression quality and image size that results in page load speeds you find preferable. However, if there aren't multiple images on this page, that might be an okay file size.

Answer (score 0):

It is because the GD library is basically creating a new image from the pixels it is given from your uploaded image. It does not care about the compression that you used.

If the original image is never actually viewed on your site, you should upload the image at the best quality you can which will give the image library a better image to recreate.

Then , as pizzasynthesis says, choose the quality setting that you want.